# Text to speech languages and voices in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, text-to-speech, speech, synthesizer

I'm running Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017.

When I check what voices that are available I only get Zira and David from Visual Studio when building a WPF app.

When I check when building a UWP app I get Bengt!

When I check in Windows 10 I only have Bengt (a Swedish one).

Is there a way I can get Bengt in to WPF if not how do I add language and voice into WPF when running Windows 10?? WPF does not get the voices installed in Windows 10!!??

Regards,

Comment: Under Windows 10, langues and voices a manages through the "Parameters==>date & time" - you can add here and will depend of your system and the defautl languge - me in french I have "Hortense" ...:-) WPF normally use them